# How to start a node server from a python shell command?

Tags: python, node.js, shell, nohup

I'm having a problem starting a node server from Python. I try to call it like this:

```
    os.system("nohup node /opt/solvoerp/solvo-erp/w_sender/app.js")
```

But I get the following error

```
(node:83046) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Page crashed!
(node:83046) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:83046) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If I execute the command from the shell the node server is executed correctly, maybe its a shell problem.

Comment: Does the node application run? You attached a few warnings, but from the text, it seeks that the node app is *not* terminated with an error. 
And another question - is this code part of a larger Python program / application? What happens when you open a python shell, import os, and then run this statement?

Comment: Also, note that the environment under which you run from the shell may be different than the one you Python code maintains. Finally, using `os.system` is, usually, the wrong way to invoke external processes. The `subprocess` module of the standard library has many functions and objects you can (and should) use for this purpose.

Comment: @Roy2012 yes is part of a wide larger python program, it's seen error from de enviroment.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron with subprocess have the same error.
Thanks I gona try to debug why the env is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

It's seen to be the node server closing after os.system or subprocess ended to call the process so I use pm2 to daemonized the node server like this:

```
from subprocess import call,check_call

check_call(['pm2', 'start', 'node /opt/solvoerp/solvo-erp/w_sender/app.js'])
```